# indexOf is not getting the exact Value in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am checking that a particular value of an array is exist in a string or not. For that I had implemented the following code

```
function Check() {
        var Value = 'I III';
        var Opt = new Array("I", "II", "III", "IV");
        for (var i = 0; i < Opt.length; i++) {
            if (Value.indexOf(Opt[i]) > -1) {
                alert("Hello");
            }
        }
    }
```

if value exists in string it should display an alert, but the problem is that it display the alert 3 times instead of 2 times, because indexOf is assuming II as a part of string because III exists in string.

Comment: You could split the value by spaces, and then calculate the difference of the arrays. The result will be the items not found in the string.

Comment: It should alert 3 times, alerting 2 times isn't correct. Because `"II"` is indeed in the string `"III"`.

Comment: II exist into the string. So there are three matches in to the given string.

Comment: You could use a regular expression to get an exact match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to work around this would be to split `Value` with a delimiter (e.g., at each space) with [`String.prototype.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
var value = 'I III'.split(' ')
var options = ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV']

options.forEach(function(option) {
  var index = value.indexOf(option)
  if (index !== -1) {
    // don't use `document.write` in general; it's just very useful in stack snippets
    document.write(index + ' : ' + value[index])
    document.write('<br>')
  }
})
```

A couple notes:

- don't capitalize your variable names; use camelCase for variables and PascalCase for classes/etc
- don't use `new Array()`; instead prefer the array literal: `[]`

Answer (score 0):

This is the another way to get the ans

> function Check() {
>
> ```
>     var Value = 'I III'.split(" "); var Opt = ["I", "II", "III", "IV"];
>
>     for (var i = 0; i < Opt.length; i++) {
>
>         if (Value.indexOf(Opt[i]) > -1) {
>
>             alert("Hello");
>
>         }
>     }
> }Check();
> ```